# Building an executable jar with Maven, Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

End goal is I am trying to build an executable jar in eclipse with maven, that's packaged with its dependencies like so. The end file structure I'm trying to accomplish is the following..

```
/target/my-distributable.zip
        |- lib (all third party jar's, which I have loaded through maven)
        |- images (the images my swing app can reference)
        |- my-application.jar (my executable jar, manifiest within with correct classpath references)
        |- my-application.properties (the properties my app reads and can modify)
        |- READ-ME.TXT
```

From here the end user would be able to unzip the distributable zip file, double click on the jar to start a java swing application which has dependencies located in the /lib directory. And there's a text editor in/as part of the swing app that I'd like to have reference images from the /images directory. What I would like to accomplish is having maven create a zip file which contains everything in this /dist folder, including my executable jar and it's dependencies located in a lib directory.

I know I need to have my exec jar's manifest include the Main class from which to run the application, and include the lib and images directory on the classpath of the manifest as well as my properties file.

I have tried several combinations of the maven shade plugin which seems to throw everything in one jar (not useful here as I need the zip with my exec jar inside, and lib outside the exec jar), and maven-assembly-plugin.

### Here is my current POM with dependencies..

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.kiosk</groupId>
  <artifactId>kiosk-application</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>

  <name>Kiosk Application</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.5</jdk.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
        <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shef</groupId>
        <artifactId>shef</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.novaworx.syntax</groupId>
        <artifactId>novaworx-syntax</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>sam.i.am</groupId>
        <artifactId>sam-i-am</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jtidy.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtidy-8</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this is my last attempt with using the maven-assembly-plugin adding to the pom above..

```
  <build>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <execute />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.5</source>
                  <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <compress>true</compress>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.kiosk.app.KioskApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>/src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>kiosk-application_${project.version}</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                    <workDirectory>${project.build.directory}/assembly/work</workDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>
```

And my

### assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileset>
        <fileset>
            <directory>target/libs</directory>
            <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</assembly>
```

My application structure..

```
/src
 |- main
    |- assembly
    |- java
       |- com
          |- kiosk
             |- etc....
    |- resources
       |- myImage.jpg
       |- my-application.properties
```

When I try to use the pom above with the build section using the maven-assembly-plugin I'm currently getting the error..

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (default) on project kiosk-application: Error reading assemblies: Error reading descriptor: /src/main/assembly/assembly.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'filesets' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n    ... @8:15) -> [Help 1]

This seems like what should be a fairly easy task to accomplish, however I have never used maven to accomplish this sort of thing and I'm having an issue orchestrating the build to produce the end result I'd like to accomplish. Is there any maven experts out there than can help point me in the right direction..?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need the libs outside the jar?

Comment: you should be using `fileSets`, right? note uppercase 'S' letter

Comment: they actually don't have to be outside the jar, when I originally built this app through netbeans, it's just the format I went with and what worked. I'm trying to use eclipse/m2e, to manage the dependencies, and set this up as a maven project. I'm open to whatever is suggested though.

Comment: @hoaz - ohhh so fileSets, not filesets..

Comment: @hoaz thanks, yeah that resolved the error I was seeing around "filesets". Thanks! I had seen an example of the assembly plugin the didn't have the camel case ;) thought it was something I was doing..

Comment: @NESPowerGlove I don't really mind where the lib resides as far as in the executable jar, or out, but I do want to expose the properties and images to my end user..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `fileSets` instead of `filesets` in your assembly.xml. Note uppercase 'S' letter. The same applies to several other XML tags.

Comment: this helped fix the issue where I was getting the error reading my assembly descriptor xml, however I'm still trying to package my zip the way I mentioned. At the moment, taking into consideration the camel casing you mentioned, I'm trying to keep my properties file and image, which are both located in my /src/main/resources/ from getting wrapped up as part of my jar.

Comment: The reason being is I was to give the end user access to the properties and access to the images to change around images without having to unpack the jar file. At the moment I've commented out my maven-assembly-plugin to try and get the jar packaging correct, then I'll add the assembly plugin back when I'm trying to package the zip..

Comment: you can exclude them using maven-resources-plugin and exclusion pattern, so they will not be placed into target dir and jar, for more details see here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: I've added an exclusion to my maven-jar-plugin to exclude resources from src/main/resources, and that works, but i do want the resources in the target right, so the maven-assembly-plugin can include them in the zip? at the moment excluding the resources from the jar plugin works, but I do need them in my zip, generated by the maven-assembly-plugin..

Comment: you can refer to `src/main/resources` instead of `target` when assembling your img/property files into zip

Comment: thanks! yeah once I adjusted where the resources were getting pulled from, it was doing what I needed. Think the biggest thing was the camel casing with the fileSets.